# Data is not inserted in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['preview'])){


echo $user = $_SESSION['ue'];
echo $title=$_POST['title'];
echo $dis=$_POST['dis'];
echo $a=$_POST['a'];
echo $b=$_POST['b'];
echo $c=$_POST['c'];
echo $d=$_POST['d'];
echo $timespan=$_POST['timespan'];

$sql="INSERT INTO survey (user, title, description, opta, optb,optc,optd) VALUES ('$user','$title', '$dis', '$a' , '$b', '$c', '$d','timespan')";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
  echo "Success";
 }
 else
  {
  echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
  }

mysqli_close($con); 
}
?>
```

Here is my code, all post variables are showed on web page, while data is not inserted in database table. also it does not show any error or exception.

Comment: `mysql_error();` wont show an error for ***mysqliiiiiii***. Use http://us1.php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: Please don't put $_POST data directly into your database, sanitize first or, since you're already using mysqli, use parametrised queries.

Comment: Column count mis match

Comment: then how can i saw exception or error?

Comment: `mysqli_error($con);` will give you your answer

Comment: You're inserting `timespan` into nothing. Also it's a static value that you're inserting. (Doesn't cause issue but I don't think that was your intention)

Answer (score 1):

1. You didn't escape your `$_POST` variables
2. Your connection to database is missing
3. `mysql_error()` will not show the errors thrown by the MySQLi functions
4. There are too many values added: 8 instead of 7

Comment: All points are irrelevant, except the 2nd one *(may be)*

Comment: the question is irrelevant.. as the points are..

Comment: Third point is very very very valid, that is exactly the reason why they are not seeing any error message

Comment: Why would you call your own answer irrelevant when ***it is*** partly relevant?

Comment: thanks for the edit, makes sense now

Comment: it isn't.. you're right.. it was just an react on the first comment..

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO survey (...)` - there is 7 columns

`VALUES (...)` - and you are sending 8 variables

Comment: This is what I was explaining in my comment

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it, I was counting :)

Comment: Yes, but keep your answer posted, this is the reason why the query fails, hence voted

Comment: @debute: Cool! You answered much earlier than Alien's comment.

Comment: Alien was faster by seconds, but it doesn't matter.